# Conditional document: how to show optional parts based on several classes

Tags: css

I have a document that has up to 6 classes to select optional parts. Some of the optional parts are within , so are in different shadow-roots, so the decision has to be passed in as CSS custom properties.

The goal is to have all the optional parts with a class that matches a class on the body to be displayed, the rest to be hidden. The optional parts have class cc, and then also the other classes that might be on the body.

Many of the ideas I thought of resulted in a combinatorial explosion of 6! (720) rules, which isn't practical.  Then I tested that opacity doesn't object to values outside the range of (0,1), so thought the following approach might work... but even the items that seem like they should sum to 0, sum to 1 instead, both in Firefox and Chrome, resulting in all text being visible, instead of just those corresponding to selected clasess!

What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>conditional text test</title>
<style>
body:not(.ab)
{
--vis-ab:0;
}
body.ab
{
--vis-ab:1;
}
body:not(.cde)
{
--vis-cde:0;
}
body.cde
{
--vis-cde:1;
}
body:not(.fghi)
{
--vis-fghi:0;
}
body.fghi
{
--vis-fghi:1;
}
body:not(.jklmn)
{
--vis-jklmn:0;
}
body.jklmn
{
--vis-jklmn:1;
}
body:not(.opqrst)
{
--vis-opqrst:0;
}
body.opqrst
{
--vis-opqrst:1;
}
body:not(.uvwxyz)
{
--vis-uvwxyz:0;
}
body.uvwxyz
{
--vis-uvwxyz:1;
}

.cc:not(.ab)
{
--has-ab:0;
}
.cc.ab
{
--has-ab:var( --vis-ab );
}
.cc:not(.cde)
{
--has-cde:0;
}
.cc.cde
{
--has-cde:var( --vis-cde );
}
.cc:not(.fghi)
{
--has-fghi:0;
}
.cc.fghi
{
--has-fghi:var( --vis-fghi );
}
.cc:not(.jklmn)
{
--has-jklmn:0;
}
.cc.jklmn
{
--has-jklmn:var( --vis-jklmn );
}
.cc:not(.opqrst)
{
--has-opqrst:0;
}
.cc.opqrst
{
--has-opqrst:var( --vis-opqrst );
}
.cc:not(.uvwxyz)
{
--has-uvwxyz:0;
}
.cc.uvwxyz
{
--has-uvwxyz:var( --vis-uvwxyz );
}
.cc
{
opacity:calc( var( --has-ab ) + var( --has-cde ) + var( --has-fghi ) + var( --has-jklmn ) + var ( --has-opqrst ) + var( --has-uvwxyz ));
}
</style>
</head>
<body class=ab>
<h1>conditional text test</h1>
<div>
<span class="cc ab">ab</span>
<span class="cc cde">cde</span>
<span class="cc fghi">fghi</span>
<span class="cc jklmn">jklmn</span>
<span class="cc opqrst">opqrst</span>
<span class="cc uvwxyz">uvwxyz</span>
</div>
<div class="cc ab fghi">ab or fghi</div>
<div class="cc ab uvwxyz">ab or uvwxyz</div>
<div class="cc opqrst fghi">opqrst or fghi</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't know what they sum to.  I was going by the fact they were all visible, with the above code. Changing from a direct calc in opacity, to calculating --opac custom property, and then using it in opacity, and using it for other things, it seems that opacity "treats it as 1", but things like line-height "treat it as 0".

Comment: It may just be me, but I have read over this question a few times now and I feel like I am still _very_ confused as to what the goal is, what the problem is, and what is being asked...

Comment: @AlexanderNied I'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend figured this out. It has a space between var and (. He submitted a bug report on Firefox DevTools https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1586556

The technique described now works fine, and my friend optimized it a bit (in the file in the bug) to reduce the number of rules required.